# How to keep variable value after reloading class

Tags: java

Hello I wrote a program that simulates a java quiz. the program has 3 nested classes first class asks for the user information(name id# etc) after all is provided a second class is called this class is the actual quiz the quiz ends when the user answers all the question or the time runs out at that point the third class scores the quiz. If the user fails he can press a button that allow him to take the quiz one more time. when the try again choice is selected a variable that keep track of tries is implemented by one. However, the problem is that the variable that keeps track of how many tries the user has taken gets wiped because the way i wrote the code the program starts all the way back from class 1 , then class 2 and class 3 and for some reason that variable goes back to its initial value when the class reloads the second time.
Is there a way i can save the variable so it does not get wiped?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should reformat your question for readability. Divide it into paragraphs. Also, show some code.

Comment: I think some persistence would help with this problem (through serialization, or database)

Comment: i don't really want to use database i will simply save the variable on a file i was just wondering if i could do something on the fly. thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to  write value in a file so that when the class get reloaded it  will read from there.

Comment: I already have a file for the student information will just add the value of the variable there and read from the file every time i run the program. I was just wondering if there was a different approach.. thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

You should have some kind of persistence on disk for your quiz information. Check for [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) to read and write to a file. There's plenty of tutorials if you google it (such as [this one](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42).)

Comment: Thanks for the link I already have methods to read and write to the file i was just wondering if i could do in a way that i wouldnt have to use files.I guess i will have to use  a file.

Comment: @rafaelzm2000 No problem. It wasn't clear in your question that you were already using files though. A friendly advice: next time make sure you specify all the required details in your question, it might help people to write answers better suited for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have something like that

```
public class A {    
    Object value;
    public void setValue(Object value) {
       this.value = value;
    }
    public Object getValue() {
       return value;
    }
}
```

So when you destroy an instance and create a new one, the value is gone.

As an academic solution you can move the `value` to the class level.

So it would be:

```
public class A {    
    static final Object[] values;
    static void setValue(Object value) {
       values[0] = value;
    }
    static Object getValue() {
       return values[0];
    }
}
```

This way `value` member belong to the class rather than an instance.

But do *NOT* do it in a real life application. Re-consider your design.